# Checking If Part of Directive Has Value - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a tabs function that will call a different href depending on the value.

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds" link="{{feed.link}}" class="TabBody{{$index+1}}   HasLink" ng-class="tab === ($index + 1) ? 'active': 'nonActive'" tabs readurlarray='{{myJsonArray}}'>  
<contents> 
</div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
    app.directive('tabs', function($http){

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          $http({
            url: 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id='+ attrs.link  +'&_render=json',
            method: 'GET'
            }).success(function(data){
              scope.data = data 
            })
        }

    }       
})
```

I need a way to check in my directive if link has a value or not before making the pipes call. There are two links that are not run through pipes so when I try to make the call there is no value for the link and I get an error. I tried something like this:

```
if($('.HasLink').attr('link').length > 0)
```

It only seemed to capture the first link's length and did not update when looking at the other links.

Here is my scope containing the links:

```
    $scope.feeds = 
  [ 
    {'link':'712aa10215bb0cf343246d724f4205a', 'name':'SM'},
    {'link':'149ce97c7ba5f03370cc1b111531e44', 'name':'CS'},
    {'name':'FORUM'}, 
    {'name':'CPSUA'}, 
    {'link':'73d3b4e72c4e1890094add0c2a2fee9', 'name':'INTRASPECTUS'},
    {'link':'6f574710e0d562406b28f1dab67fff3', 'name':'SALES'},
    {'name':'LIBRARY'},
    {'link':'e05db886024ddaa70b08ddfbb794875', 'name':'KY'},
    {'link':'5dcd5fd3417519d2dce9e3a66690da6', 'name':'UK'},
    {'link':'27206e0fbd6b4eca9673c3dcb2d4fa7', 'name':'THE FEED'}
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.directive('tabs', function($http){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        if (attrs.link != ''){  
          $http({
            url: 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id='+ attrs.link  +'&_render=json',
            method: 'GET'
            }).success(function(data){
              scope.data = data 
            })
            }
        }  
    }       
})
```

By putting the if statement after where link is defined the value is easily accessed and can be compared from there.

Answer (score 0):

Using a filter: http://plnkr.co/edit/OLCqIy3JwhUZnB9HCUWV

```
.filter('yourFilter', function () {
    return function (feeds) {
        return feeds.filter(function (feed) {
            return feed.link !== undefined;
        });
    }
});


<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | yourFilter">
    {{feed}}
</div>
```

Comment: Doing it that way my attrs.link comes back as undefined. In my return, link is defined through the function(scope, elem, attrs) I believe. Is there a way to reference my link that way in the if statement?

Comment: I added the scope that contains the links above. Adding in scope.link comes back as scope being undefined.

Comment: Let us just ignore the feeds that do not have a link using a filter

Comment: Okay. How would I set something like that up?

Answer (score 0):

please see here http://jsbin.com/lativa/1/

```
  app.directive('tabs', function($http){

    return {
        restrict: "A",
       scope:{
        dlink : "=",
        dname: "="
      },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
if(scope.dlink) {

          $http({
            url: 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id='+ attrs.link  +'&_render=json',
            method: 'GET'
            }).success(function(data){
              scope.data = data 
            })
        }
}

    }       
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds" link="{{feed.link}}" class="TabBody{{$index+1}}   HasLink" ng-class="tab === ($index + 1) ? 'active': 'nonActive'"
     tabs dlink="feed.link" dname="feed.name" >  

</div>
```